# React Leaflet: FlyToBounds programmatically on prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

The react-leaflet map component is rendered properly based on a polyline. The polyline starts perfectly centered in the middle of the screen.

Here is my issue: I want to recenter the map to the polyline programmatically, because the interface takes up space of the map like a toggle button.

Without react I know how to do it:

```
 map.invalidateSize();
 let bounds = L.latLngBounds(patharray);
 map.flyToBounds(bounds);
```

But with react I do not have a clue how to access these methods.

I tried to in my   component like this:

```
ref={(ref) => this.mapRef = ref}
```

And then use the ref in ComponentWillReceiveProps() like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const {flyToBounds} = this.props

    console.log(this.mapRef)

    if (flyToBounds) {
      this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.invalidateSize()
      this.mapRef.current.leafletElement.flyToBounds(this.bounds)
    }
 }
```

However the functions invalidateSize and flyToBounds are not available. So, now I am stuck.

Comment: there are methods to manipulate state of the map, like `setView`. The docs are saying it _Sets the view of the map (geographical center and zoom) with the given animation options._ . Is that what you were looking for?  If you posted your component, maybe we could help

Comment: ah, and there is a `flyToBounds` described in docs, which I have never heard of and that is why were promoting setView initially.

Comment: setView should also suffice. Here is the entire component: https://pastebin.com/d2h8hUr9

Comment: whoah, that is gonna be tough even to start, beacause you have lots of custom import etc. just inside `componentWillReceiveProps` try `this.setView(latLngOfCenter, numberZoom)` which are also prbably taken from props. Here are [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-setview)

Comment: sorry that doesnt help. Its https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet Im using

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

We have **bounds** prop available in Map react-leaflet, it helps to recenter the map according all provided lat lng array.

bounds: bounds (optional): A rectangle for the map to contain. It will be centered, and the map will zoom in as close as it can while still showing the full bounds. Changes are compared using the  equals() method of LatLngBounds.

Please have a look at link https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components